# lit-translate - get() not returning the key's value

Tags: javascript, lit-element

I'm using the excellent JS i18n library [`lit-translate`](https://github.com/andreasbm/lit-translate/) for a LitElement-project. If I understand correctly, `get("foo.bar")` is supposed to get the value of that key from a JSON file that contains the translations.

In my project, however, **`get("foo.bar")` doesn't return the value of the key, but returns `[foo.bar]` instead.** `translate("foo.bar")` works, but only inside a LitElement's HTML structure like `<p>${translate("foo.bar")}</p>`. Outside of such a structure, for example in the LitElement's `constructor()` part or simply outside of the LitElement class definition, `translate("foo.bar")` only returns `part => { partCache.set(part, cb); updatePart(part, cb); }`.

How can I simply get the value of a key through `get()`? I'm still a JavaScript novice and probably overlooking something, but what? Help is appreciated!

Here's my code (the relevant parts of it):

```
// app-shell.js

// … several module imports …

import {
    registerTranslateConfig,
    use,
    get,
    translate
} from "@appnest/lit-translate";

// … the LitElement class and other stuff …
// the lit-element contains the following code, which works like a charm:
//  render() {
//      return html`
//          <p>${translate("header.title")}</p> // RETURNS REAL RESULT
//      `;
//  }

// registers AppShell as as web component named app-shell with the browser
customElements.define("app-shell", AppShell);

// registers the translation loader
registerTranslateConfig({
    loader: lang =>
        fetch(`../../_locales/${lang}/i18n.json`).then(res => res.json())
});

// sets the app's language
use(store.getState().app_shell.language); // store… returns "en", "de" or "fr"

// updates the application bar's title and the local storage entry
const title = get("header.title"); // RETURNS "[header.title]". WHY?
document.getElementById("title").innerText = title;
localStorage.setItem("title", title);
```

Comment: can you create a simple reproduction of your error? or maybe add the relevant code here?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't just a case of the translations not having loaded yet before you call `get`? What if you move that logic until after the `fetch(...).then(...)` completes?

Comment: See https://github.com/andreasbm/lit-translate/blob/8f313900f4cea95aa8eca7e7409dcf8815d58df2/README.md#-wait-for-strings-to-be-loaded-before-displaying-the-component; seems to reference how to wait for translations to be loaded.

Comment: @Jacob: You're right! I implemented that and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been identified (see comments to my question). Here's what was missing in my LitElement:

```
//
constructor() {
    super();
    // defers the first update of the component until the strings have been loaded
    // to avoid empty strings being shown
    this.hasLoadedStrings = false;
}

// overwrites default updating behavior
shouldUpdate(changedProperties) {
    return this.hasLoadedStrings && super.shouldUpdate(changedProperties);
}

// loads the initial language and marks that the strings have been loaded
async connectedCallback() {
    // sets the app's language;
    await use(store.getState().app_shell.language);
    this.hasLoadedStrings = true;
    super.connectedCallback();
}
```